# Lazy Load markdown content in Vue 3 + Vite

Tags: performance, vuejs3, lazy-loading, vite

i have an array with objects and nested objects like example below. This array contains 110 blog posts which i scrape from Strapi through the API.

Each blog post contain "blogPost_Content_before_read_more" with all the content.

{
...,
"blogPost_Content_before_read_more": "Este modelo é composto por 15 caixas, cada qual explicando um ponto específico do comportamento de uma persona](https://jornio-strapi.s3.amazonaws.com/exemplo_gratuito_de_persona_larissa_eletronico_persona_aprenda_o_que_e_2fd3418f1a.webp)\n\n### Por que criar uma Persona?\n\nO objetivo é criar uma representação do seu público que facilite o diálogo com ele.\n\nAfinal,...""
}

I'm using Vue 3 + Vite (SPA, not SSR) in my blog post, and rendering the markdown content using [vue3-markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-markdown-it).

But when i analyze the performance of the blog post page into PageSpeed Insights it shows a lack of optimization to lazy loading offscreen images.

So i'd like to add lazy loading to these images.

Does anyone have a clue about it?

I'd like the images to load the use user scrolls, i mean, the basic concept of lazy load the image when the user will see.

i was thinking to use [defineAsyncComponent](https://learnvue.co/articles/lazy-load-components) and was wondering it make sense, as looks like it will load the whole "blogPost_Content_before_read_more".